# What are the correct terms for these visualization components?

Tags: interaction-design, info-visualisation, charts, infographic

#### What is the proper term for a vertical line on a visualization that follows a mouse cursor?

<sub>*Nb, screenshots have removed my mouse cursor but it exists on the same vertical plane as the dot in the second figure in both visualizations.*</sub>

[image: vertical line mouse cursor]

What is the name of a point on a visualization that follows a mouse cursor?

[image: dot following vertical position of cursor]

Both are supplementary mouse cursors, but do they have a canonical name?

<sup>Please tell me if these questions should be split into two or better suited for a different SE site.</sup>

Comment: I cannot think of well-accepted terms for the first. I will note that (1) on a timeline, the vertical bar would be the playhead, and (2) the intersecting value is a simply a "data label", but it happens to be a data label with a varying position. Perhaps a "data inspector"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are often referred in high charts as **[x-axis crosshairs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip#cross).**

Also in **[Zing Chart](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/interactive-features/crosshairs/)**

[image]